# SPARQL query select top object property in Protege

Tags: syntax, sparql, protege

I currently make SPARQL queries for android API about finding the right dog breeds, based on hypoallergenic, purpose, cost, and energy level.

Here is the class hierarchy screenshot :
[image]

Here is the data property hierarchy :
[image]

Here is object property hierarchy :
[image]

Here are individuals :
[image]

**the result I want is the dog breeds** (beagle, basenji, dachshund wirehaired, saluki, dachshund miniature, whippet, as seen as individual in picture 4), which `hasPurpose is Hound`.
I try this query but it didn't show what i wanted.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?individual ?hasPurpose
WHERE {
    ?individual rdf:rdfs hasPurpose:Hound
}
```

Comment: ok, you know nothing about SPARQL and RDF ... what is `rdf:rdfs` for a predicate? `hasPurpose:` is a defined prefix?

Comment: and what did you do in your ontology?! you have an individual `Hound`, right? And you related this to some other individuals via the `topObjectProperty`? For example, you added `Hound topObjectProperty Beagle` - What kind of information does this express? Why don't you say `Hound hasPurpose Beagle`?

Comment: was spent almost half a year figuring out how it works, actually still doenst really sure how it works, rdf:rdfs just one of my attempt trying to do this. sorry but can you tell me more about Hound hasPurpose Beagle?By Hound topObjectProperty Beagle,  i mean all the breeds in topObjectProperty  is a member of Hound group

Comment: `Hound` is one of purpose and not a breed. it's supposed to be `Beagle hasPurpose Hound`, not really sure if my ontology is represented what I'm trying to make.


so I have 20 dog breeds, it 'hasPurpose'

There is 7 kinds of purpose. `Hound` is one of them.

I look forward to your reply, thank you before

Comment: *"By Hound topObjectProperty Beagle, i mean all the breeds in topObjectProperty is a member of Hound group"* - to be honest, I don't understand this sentence. What means *"all the breeds in topObjectProperty"* - this isn't anything meaningful. `topObjectProperty` is the most general object property in OWL by definition. Any object property is a subproperty of `topObjectProperty`. An object property relates two individuals.

Comment: *"Hound is one of purpose and not a breed."* - also something that I do not understand, sorry. `Hound` is an individual in your ontology that belongs to the class `purpose`. So the question is, what do you want to express? From my point of view, a `Beagle` should probably has the purpose `Hound`, right? that means, you have to add a property assertion to the individual `Beagle`, i.e. `Beagle hasPurspose Hound` - what you did is 1) not using `hasPrupose` and 2) the wrong "direction"